# Find out in which repository the commit was added

Tags: git

We have two git repositories containing two distinct, but very similar projects.

The first project is the main project (MAIN hereinafter), and the second project is a derivation from MAIN (DERIV hereinafter).

*EDIT:
Please note that these are not different branches in the same repo, but two separate repos. In each repo we maintain just one branch `master`.*

We work on these two projects in parallel, but the basic assumption is that every change to MAIN should also be applied to DERIV. We satisfy this by issuing periodical pulls from MAIN to DERIV.

The questions:

1. When executing `git log` in DERIV, can I see, for each commit, in a clone of which repository it was added?

   *EDIT:
   The question is whether this is doable while both repos maintain a single branch `master`. If not, then the question becomes whether using different names for branches in two repos will solve this issue.*
2. Can I find out the dates of pulls from MAIN to DERIV?

   *EDIT: 
   The issue with `git log` is the following: when I work on MAIN project, I clone from MAIN repo to a local machine, do some work (multiple commits), pull from MAIN and resolve conflicts (if any), push to MAIN/master. The last commit's message is `Merge branch 'master' of MAIN`.
   When I pull  from MAIN to DERIV and resolve the conflicts the message is `Merge branch 'master' of MAIN` - the same as above.
   I would like to know in a clone of which repo was the above (merge-resolution) commit added.*
3. Can I see who performed a pull from MAIN to DERIV?
4. Do you think that pulling from MAIN is the best approach? For instance, the same results could be achieved with cherry-picking (and, maybe, rebase).

Thanks

Comment: So MAIN and DERIV are different branches of the same project, right? That is, they belong to the same repository, even if you work on them on different machines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[EDIT : following updated question]

If you register both remotes, you can see which commits are registered on `MAIN` and which are registered on `DERIV`.

```
$ git clone gitserver:deriv.git
$ cd deriv
$ git remote add main gitserver:main.git
$ git fetch main
```

You should see a branch `main/master` in your local repo, which will tell you which commits are part of `MAIN` and which aren't.

[/EDIT]

Short answer :

1. yes
2. no, but it probably doesn't matter
3. no, but it probably doesn't matter
4. yes

*about git log :*

I assume you started your `DERIV` repository by running `git clone MAIN DERIV`, and that you want a workflow where you pull from `MAIN`, but never push.

In that case, the `DERIV` repository is "aware" of the existence of `MAIN`, and git commands (mainly `git fetch`) allow you to integrate `MAIN`'s history into `DERIV`.

Each time you run `git fetch` (`git pull` is actually `git fetch` followed by `git merge`), you will import `MAIN`'s history into `DERIV`, and its current branches will be visible and tagged with the `origin/` prefix.

- you can run `git branch -r` to see the list of branches from `MAIN`
- you can run `git log origin/branchname` to view the history of `branchname` on `MAIN`
- if you run `git log --decorate`, each commit will appear with the names of branches and tags pointing to it
- these annotations will also appear in graphic tools like `gitk`

You can then spot which branches in your `DERIV` projects have integrated changes from the `MAIN` project.

If you have some branches in `DERIV` tracking branches in `MAIN` (it is the default behavior of `master`), `git status` will inform you if `DERIV`'s branch is missing commits from `MAIN`'s branch.

If you mainly use the command line, two commands are very handy :

```
git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all
```

You can [add them as shortcuts in your config file](http://blog.kfish.org/2010/04/git-lola.html).

*about who pulled and when*

You will see the dates and authors of `MAIN`'s commits, you will see the dates and authors of merges in `DERIV`'s commits, when there will be conflicts with `MAIN`. You won't see exactly who pulled the history in though.

`git fetch` is actually a (almost) harmless command which will import `MAIN`'s history and not meddle with `DERIV` branches (what it *will* do is add a bunch of commits to your repository, and move all the `origin/*` branches which are imported).

*pull vs cherry-pick*

It's easier to track differences between branches head (`git` has all this internal mechanism for tracking and merging *branches*) than to try to achieve the same result by hand (e.g. : using `cherry-pick` and `rebase`, and try to track by hand which commits have been ported and which have not).

**What else ?**

`git fetch / git merge / git pull` is definitely the way to go to keep the two repositories in sync. What you need is a set of rules for *branches*.

Maybe you are only interested in some particular branches of `MAIN` (`master`, `release`, ...) and not in other ones (`dev`, `test`, `tmp` ...) : you can configure your `DERIV` repository to import only some selected branches by default ([details here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-The-Refspec)).

It is handy to have local branches mirroring remote branches, but maybe you don't want `DERIV:master` to be "hard-linked" to `MAIN:master`.

If you want to unlink `master` and `origin/master`, you can edit the `.git/config` file and remove the section `[branch "master"]`.

If you want to create a local branch which tracks a remote branch with a different name, you can run :

```
git branch main/v10 --track origin/v10
```

`main/v10` will be a local branch, which tracks the remote `v10` branch.

**Conclusion**

A git answer is rarely complete without pointing to [The Book](http://git-scm.com/book). Take the time to read it, it has a very high `relevant explanation / line of text` ratio. [Chapter 3](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching) is about branching and merging.

Comment: Reminds me of [Vicky Pollard](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7rnVWo7SGM)! (Sorry, couldn't resist :)

Comment: @LeGEC, it is great overview, but still not answers my questions. I'm adding clarifications to the question.

Comment: @LeGEC, DERIV/master is neither monitoring MAIN/master nor do we want it to.